# GWT JSNI and return function - need advice

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I was looking all around the samples but still can't get it... How to write such kind of function in JSNI as

```
function test(a)
{
  return a+' is parameter';
}
```

I mean to be able get JS function return value with GWT...
?

All useful comments are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSNI function calls are defined like that:

```
public final native String test(String a) /*-{
        return a + 'is parameter;
}-*/;
```

The important part of the function signature is **final native** and the opening and closing brackets.

Fore more information on how to write and use JSNI see [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

If you have more complex return types also check out [JavaScript Overlays Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html).

Comment: Yes, I know they are :) I mean how to emulate the JS "return a+' is parameter'" to get it with GWT to use it next with Java?

Comment: I am not sure I get it. So you want to have a plain javascript function (i.e. test) and then call it from GWT and work with the returned string?

Comment: That's right :) But how the JS code can "return" value back to gwt to work with? Will the native, as you answered, "return a+' is parameter';" really return value right to GWT?

Comment: Emm and can native contain subfunctions? Or can it return a function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsArrayString` if you wish to return an array of the string.

This is helpful to overcome the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$
>   cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;